# Kibana - update default search query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to elastic search and Kibana. In Kibana, while trying to fetch elastic search document in json, by default a bsearch query been executed with wildcard field search as below

> fields: [{field: "*", include_unmapped: "true"}, {field: "timestamp",
> format: "date_time"}]

[image: Elastic search - bsearch]

This in turn returns all the document values as array under fields section. I need to turn off requesting fields in search query and its enough to have _source metadata in my json.

[image: Fields-Json]

How to update the default query been searched in kibana? Thanks in advance

**Installed elastic search version - 7.17.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Advanced Settings, you can turn on "Read fields from source" instead of using the Fields API, but it's soon going to be deprecated:

[image: fields]